# How to add custom link preview to mattermost

Tags: mattermost

I'am looking for a way to implement custom link preview for our task system (MantisBT). Essentially i would like to create some sort of plugin which would be able to capture links in specific format (`https://tasks.com/b/1234`). Get simple details of given task using REST api from internal task server and show them as message attachment (ex. task summary, assignee and status).

Unfortunatelly i cant find any info if it is even possible not speaking about some more detailed steps to do such think.

So to sum it up, someone sends a message:

```
Hello can you please look at https://tasks.com/b/1234
```

When this is send, i would like to see something like this:

```
Hello can you please look at https://tasks.com/b/1234

-----------------------------
| 1234: Bug in new system   |
| assignee: John            |
| status: new               |
-----------------------------
```

Essentially creating own link visualizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`registerLinkTooltipComponent`](https://developers.mattermost.com/extend/plugins/webapp/reference/#registerLinkTooltipComponent) plugin hook to display a custom component on hovering on a link. You'll be able to filter for specific links and display your custom component for any link you want to support.

You can refer the GitHub plugin as an example - https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-plugin-github/tree/master/webapp/src/components/link_tooltip

[image]

Comment: @sadovsf did this help you? If yes, please accept the answer.